# Hibernate: could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, jersey

In my Hibernate code, I am executing a SQL command. There I have a `LIKE` statement. The code is below.

```
public List<Object[]> searchProducts(String searchTerm, Session session) {
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT product_request_advertisement.idproduct_request_advertisement,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.user_iduser,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.product_idproduct,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.product_units_idproduct_units,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.type,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.grade,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.quantity,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.expected_price,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.required_place,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.required_date,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.extra_information,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.expire_on,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.delete_timestamp,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.date_created,\n"
                + "                product_request_advertisement.last_updated,\n"
                + "                user.name,\n"
                + "                product_unit.unit_name\n"
                + "                FROM product_request_advertisement\n"
                + "                INNER JOIN user ON product_request_advertisement.user_iduser = user.iduser\n"
                + "                INNER JOIN product_unit ON product_unit.idproduct_unit = product_request_advertisement.product_units_idproduct_units\n"
                + "                INNER JOIN product ON product.idproduct = product_request_advertisement.product_idproduct\n"
                + "                WHERE product_request_advertisement.delete_timestamp is null\n"
                + "                AND product_request_advertisement.approved=true \n"
                + "                AND product_request_advertisement.type LIKE '% :searchTerm %' or product.product_name LIKE '% :searchTerm %' \n"
                + "                GROUP BY product_request_advertisement.idproduct_request_advertisement");

        System.out.println("DAO SEARCHTERM: " + searchTerm);
        query.setParameter("searchTerm", searchTerm);

        List<Object[]> list = query.list();
        return list;
    }
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [searchTerm]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493)
    at lk.maningmarket.api.dao.product_request_advertisement.ProductRequestAdvertisementDAOImpl.searchProducts(ProductRequestAdvertisementDAOImpl.java:206)
    at lk.maningmarket.api.service.ProductRequestAdvertisementService.searchProducts(ProductRequestAdvertisementService.java:685)
    at lk.maningmarket.api.rest.RequestAdvertisementJSONService.searchProducts(RequestAdvertisementJSONService.java:155)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This is probably due to an incorrect way I have written the `searchTerm` between the `LIKE` command, but how can I solve this?

Comment: @Jason: This is not HQL, This is SQL. Then this is an issue regarding `LIKE` statement. Error is same but can caused by many issues. So not a duplicate.

Comment: @PeakGen That may be, but the solution is basically the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using this `LIKE` expression:

```
LIKE :searchTerm
```

And then bind as follows:

```
query.setParameter("searchTerm", "%" + searchTerm "%");
```

This is, you bind a single string, which is whatever the `LIKE` expression should be after the desired string has been bound.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alternatively use `LIKE '%' || :searchTerm || '%'` (in some dialects, `+` instead of `||`)